# Possible to Force IPv6 Connections without Privacy Extensions only?

Tags: ipv6

I am sorry I am not a software engineer myself but I need to know this for a broader research paper around this topic. 
Is it possible for a Web-Server/Website to only accept IPv6 connections without privacy extensions-thus making it possible to identify every computer that connects to that server?

Thank you very much for your help in advance,
John

Comment: You can require that the middle bytes of the host portion of the header are ff:fe, but that still doesn't stop someone from randomising the rest. So it's a pretty stupid idea.

Answer (score 1):

The client decides the source address, not the server. The server can't know the policy at the client side and can't influence it.

Comment: Thanks for your help-i thought the server could see the clients adress and refuse to connect if it is not in ipv6. Also, I thought that maybe it is somehow visible if someone was using privacy extensions. I am sorry if the idea sounds stupid to you but I still do not see the initial question answered, cheers

Comment: The answer is 'no'. It's not possible on the server-side to see if someone is using privacy extensions. It is therefore not possible for the server to make that decision.